# C++ Templates: Error while instantiate object

Tags: c++, templates

i try to instantiate a class template with an int Variable. 
template class:

```
template <int N>
class GRAPH {
    // ...
}
```

when i try to do this like:

```
    GRAPH<100> mygraph;
```

it works fine. But when I do this like:

```
int maxVertices=100;
GRAPH<maxVertices> mygraph;
```

I get following error:

invalid type in declaration before ';' token

Can someone help me?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to

```
const int maxVertices=100;
GRAPH<maxVertices> mygraph;
```

Template parameters are evaluated at compile time, thus you can only pass a constant expression as template parameter here.

Answer (score 0):

Template parameters are resolved at compile-time.  Since `maxVertices` isn't a constant, its value isn't known at compile-time, so you get an error.